# MVVMCross Features

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'am a newbie in MVVMCross and I was wondering if an expert can answer a couple of my questions.

1. I want to handle my virtual keyboard (custom keyboard(similar to the android keyboard) on my android device to type only at a focused edittextfield. I dont know how to do that.
2. Is there a way to access the control's (any control - button , edittextfield) properties directly from my viewmodel? Maybe you can explain a best practice of handling control events through viewmodels?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.

What I was looking actually was the FindByViewID in my view.cs  to get the control properties and events and then pass it to properties in the Viewmodel as you mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

1. No idea what exactly you mean here?
2. No, this is and should not be possible by design.
   -> You should not have any direct access from the ViewModel to your View. The connection between this two elements is done using DataBinding. This means whenever you want to access a property of the control, expose a property on your ViewModel for this and bind them together in the View.

For Example when you want to access the "Text"-Property of your EditText. Then Create a Property on your ViewModel (YourTextProperty for example) and then use DataBinding.
On Android this would like something like:

```
<EditText local:MvxBind="Text YourTextProperty" />
```

The MvvmCross Binding-Engine will then automatically execute the setter of your property when the control does change this value...

Comment: For extending mvvmcross bindings to new controls and new events, you can also see the custom control and custom binding tutorials in the n+1 videos - http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com